# Decompile android APK with Apktool for analysis?

Tags: android, decompiling, apktool

On apktool homepage [apktool.org](https://apktool.org) it say.

> Not interested in rebuilding? Just attach **-a** to any command. Apktool
> will do its best to rip apart the resources and manifest for easy
> inspection.

I tried `apktool -a d myfile.apk` not working, how do i use analyze switch `-a`?

Comment: @Robert if i do `apktool.bat d myfile.apk -a` getting error `Missing argument for option -a`, i think its generic error, because even if i do not existing option `-z` instead of `-a` apktool reports same error. When i run `apktool --help` it does not list option `-a` perhaps they pulled out that option, but forgot to update website?

Answer (score 0):

Your command has two problems:

1. You are using the wrong option: `-a` is wrong. The apktool website contains the text:

> Not interested in rebuilding? Just attach `-m` to any disassemble command.

2. The argument ordering is wrong

The apktool help shows the correct command-line and argument ordering:

```
apktool [-q|--quiet OR -v|--verbose] d[ecode] [options] <file_apk>
```

I your case you use the `decode` command and the option `-m`, therefore you are getting the command-line:

```
apktool d -m myfile.apk
```